# How do I pass a variable inside my img src in the following :<img alt="Avatar" src=`https://graph.facebook.com/${snAvatarSnuid}/picture`>

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, web-frontend

I am trying to pass a variable `snAvatarSnuid` inside the img src after facebook.com/ and before /picture as below

```
<img alt="Avatar" src=`https://graph.facebook.com/${snAvatarSnuid}/picture`>
```

Note: 1) `https://graph.facebook.com/` & `/picture` part of src remains same only the value of `snAvatarSnuid` has to be added in between.
2) `snAvatarSnuid` is defined in data of Vue component

where am I wrong ? how do I solve it ?

Comment: You need to bind the source dynamically in this case. Use :src instead of src.

Comment: tried :src=`https://graph.facebook.com/${snAvatarSnuid}/picture`, doesn't work

Comment: inspect and check if the path/src is correct or not. What's the value for snAvatarSnuid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind. Moreover you have to use quotes in a proper way:

```
<img alt="Avatar" :src="`https://graph.facebook.com/${snAvatarSnuid}/picture`">
```

When you bind attributes, everything inside the quotes will be treated as a javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace your back tilts with quotes and enclose your variable in double brackets:

```
<img alt="Avatar" src='https://graph.facebook.com/{{snAvatarSnuid}}/picture'>
```